# Why is this DP algo slower than the brute forcea algo?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, hashmap, dynamic-programming

I am working on implementing the longest palindromic substring problem and I followed the approach with DP and extra `O(N^2)` (yes I know there is an even more efficient algorithm but I am not interested in that in this post).
My implementation which basically uses the recurrence:

```
P(i, j) = P(i + 1, j - 1) ^ s[i] == s[j]
```

builds the relevant table but the run time is much slower than expected.
It does give the correct output if I run it in my IDE after several seconds (15+) but it is rejected by any online judge as too slow. I am not sure where the issue is since I am using **memorization**. So there is not recomputation of the same cases.
The strings that are starting to show that the algorithm has a performance issue are over 900 chars long.

**Update**
I am updating the question to add full source code and test case

**Dynamic Programming approach O(N^2) time and O(N^2) space (not accepted and too slow)**

```
public static String longestPalindromeDP(String s) {
        Map<List<Integer>, Boolean> cache = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
                populateTable(s, i, j, cache);
            }
        }
        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
                if(cache.get(Arrays.asList(i, j))) {
                    if(Math.abs(start - end) < Math.abs(i - j)) {
                        start = i;
                        end = j;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return s.substring(start, end + 1);
    }

private static boolean populateTable(String s, int i, int j, Map<List<Integer>, Boolean> cache) {
        if(i == j) {
            cache.put(Arrays.asList(i, j), true);
            return true;
        }
        if(Math.abs(i - j) == 1) {
            cache.put(Arrays.asList(i, j), s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j));
            return s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j);
        }

        if(cache.containsKey(Arrays.asList(i, j))) {
            return cache.get(Arrays.asList(i, j));
        }

        boolean res = populateTable(s, i + 1, j - 1, cache) && s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j);
        cache.put(Arrays.asList(i, j), res);
        cache.put(Arrays.asList(j, i), res);
        return res;
    }
```

This is very slow in the `populateTable` but once it finishes the result is correct.

**Brute force O(N^3) time and O(1) space: much faster and accepted**

```
public static String longestPalindromeBruteForce(String s) {
        if(s.length() == 1) {
            return s;
        }
        String result = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            for(int j = i + 1; j <= s.length(); j++) {
                String tmp = s.substring(i, j);
                if(isPalindrome(tmp)) {
                    if(tmp.length() > result.length()) {
                        result = tmp;
                        if(result.length() == s.length()) {
                            return result;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
        for(int i = 0, j = s.length() - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
            if(s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(j)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Testing and input:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String string1 = "civilwartestingwhetherthatnaptionoranynartionsoconceivedandsodedicatedcanlongendureWeareqmetonagreatbattlefiemldoftzhatwarWehavecometodedicpateaportionofthatfieldasafinalrestingplaceforthosewhoheregavetheirlivesthatthatnationmightliveItisaltogetherfangandproperthatweshoulddothisButinalargersensewecannotdedicatewecannotconsecratewecannothallowthisgroundThebravelmenlivinganddeadwhostruggledherehaveconsecrateditfaraboveourpoorponwertoaddordetractTgheworldadswfilllittlenotlenorlongrememberwhatwesayherebutitcanneverforgetwhattheydidhereItisforusthelivingrathertobededicatedheretotheulnfinishedworkwhichtheywhofoughtherehavethusfarsonoblyadvancedItisratherforustobeherededicatedtothegreattdafskremainingbeforeusthatfromthesehonoreddeadwetakeincreaseddevotiontothatcauseforwhichtheygavethelastpfullmeasureofdevotionthatweherehighlyresolvethatthesedeadshallnothavediedinvainthatthisnationunsderGodshallhaveanewbirthoffreedomandthatgovernmentofthepeoplebythepeopleforthepeopleshallnotperishfromtheearth";
        //final String string2 = "ibvjkmpyzsifuxcabqqpahjdeuzaybqsrsmbfplxycsafogotliyvhxjtkrbzqxlyfwujzhkdafhebvsdhkkdbhlhmaoxmbkqiwiusngkbdhlvxdyvnjrzvxmukvdfobzlmvnbnilnsyrgoygfdzjlymhprcpxsnxpcafctikxxybcusgjwmfklkffehbvlhvxfiddznwumxosomfbgxoruoqrhezgsgidgcfzbtdftjxeahriirqgxbhicoxavquhbkaomrroghdnfkknyigsluqebaqrtcwgmlnvmxoagisdmsokeznjsnwpxygjjptvyjjkbmkxvlivinmpnpxgmmorkasebngirckqcawgevljplkkgextudqaodwqmfljljhrujoerycoojwwgtklypicgkyaboqjfivbeqdlonxeidgxsyzugkntoevwfuxovazcyayvwbcqswzhytlmtmrtwpikgacnpkbwgfmpavzyjoxughwhvlsxsgttbcyrlkaarngeoaldsdtjncivhcfsaohmdhgbwkuemcembmlwbwquxfaiukoqvzmgoeppieztdacvwngbkcxknbytvztodbfnjhbtwpjlzuajnlzfmmujhcggpdcwdquutdiubgcvnxvgspmfumeqrofewynizvynavjzkbpkuxxvkjujectdyfwygnfsukvzflcuxxzvxzravzznpxttduajhbsyiywpqunnarabcroljwcbdydagachbobkcvudkoddldaucwruobfylfhyvjuynjrosxczgjwudpxaqwnboxgxybnngxxhibesiaxkicinikzzmonftqkcudlzfzutplbycejmkpxcygsafzkgudy";

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        String palindromic = longestPalindromeDP(string1);
        long elapsed = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(System.nanoTime() - startTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

        System.out.println(elapsed);
        System.out.println(palindromic);

    }
```

**The BruteForce finishes in 0 seconds.

The DynamicProgramming finishes in up to 9 seconds (depending on the machine)**

What is the problem here?
I understand that there can be some optimization to improve the performance but how is it possible that the O(N^3) outperforms the O(N^2) since I use memoization?

**Update**
Update based on the answer of @CahidEnesKeleş

I replaced the `List<Integer>` as key with a custom object:

```
class IdxPair {  
   int i;
   int j;  
   IdxPair(int i, int j) {
     this.i = i;
     this.j = j;  
   }  

   @Override  
   public boolean equals(Object o) {  
      if(o == null || !(o instanceof IdxPair)) return false;  
      if(this == o ) return true;  
      IdxPair other = (IdxPair) o;  
      return this.i == other.i && this.j == other.j;  
   }  

   @Override 
   public int hashCode() {  
     int h = 31;  
     h = 31 * i + 37;  
     h = (37 * h) + j;    
     return h;  
   }  
}
```

Although a couple of test cases that previously failed, now pass it is still too slow overall and rejected by online judges.

Comment: Why is the better algorithm not relevant to this?

Comment: The pair 2 and 73 is exactly the same as 73 and 2 so you do the same work twice. Hence the simplest improvement is: iterate `j` from `i` instead from `0`.

Comment: @CiaPan: Yes but I cache them so I never recompute them. Check `cache.put(new Pair(j, i), result); // add the reverse too ` Would it still be an issue you think?

Comment: @LouisWasserman: I meant that I would like to understand the issue in this approach and not focus on whether I should follow another more optimal approach e.g. Manacher's algorithm or expanding from the center

Comment: @LouisWasserman: In my understanding the approach performance wise should be good i.e. O(N^2) with extra space.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Also I have tried a O(N^3) algorithm (for all substrings linearly check if they are palindromic) and that is even faster than the above (and accepted) for the same input so there must be some wrong with my implementation and not with the fact that there is O(N) approach

Comment: Can you show us your IdxPair class?

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Updated the post. It is kind of hacky I have to admint

Comment: I was mostly looking for the `hashCode` implementation, which isn't terrible.  Not great for this use case, but not terrible.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: I updated the post. I removed that class to avoid confusion. I added full source code example with sample inputs and measured it

Comment: The brute force solution is O(n^3) because of `substring` mainly. Call to this function can be avoided.

Comment: @Damien: It is because of `isPalindrome`. I guess you mean use the `char[]` instead, but in any case it is still much faster than the DP approach

Comment: @Damien: Did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: @Jim What I means is that the brute force procedure could be improved, while staying brute force, by avoiding useless copy with `substring`. It should become O(n^2) in most cases. However, it doesn't explain why your method is so slow.

Comment: @Damien: But without the copy with substring, it would still be O(N^3) due to the call to `isPalindrome()`, isn't that right?

Comment: In most cases, this function returns false very rapidly, except maybe in some corner cases, not the one you have selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using c-like arrays instead of `HashMap`, here is the code:

```
public static String longestPalindromeDP(String s) {
    int[][] cache = new int[s.length()][s.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
            cache[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
            populateTable(s, i, j, cache);
        }
    }
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
            if(cache[i][j] == 1) {
                if(Math.abs(start - end) < Math.abs(i - j)) {
                    start = i;
                    end = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return s.substring(start, end + 1);
}

private static boolean populateTable(String s, int i, int j, int[][] cache) {
    if(i == j) {
        cache[i][j] = 1;
        return true;
    }
    if(Math.abs(i - j) == 1) {
        cache[i][j] = s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j) ? 1 : 0;
        return s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j);
    }

    if (cache[i][j] != -1) {
        return cache[i][j] == 1;
    }

    boolean res = populateTable(s, i + 1, j - 1, cache) && s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j);
    cache[i][j] = res ? 1 : 0;
    cache[j][i] = res ? 1 : 0;
    return res;
}
```

This code works faster than brute force approach. In my computer old dp finishes in ~5000 milliseconds, new dp finishes ~30 milliseconds, and bruteforce finishes in ~100 milliseconds.

Now that we know the reason for slowness, I conducted further experiments and measured the following codes' running time.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        cache.put(Arrays.asList(i, j), true);
    }
}
```

This code finishes in 2000 milliseconds. I further divided the expression to find exactly what is the source of slowness.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        Arrays.asList(i, j);
    }
}
```

This code finishes in 37 milliseconds.

```
Map<Integer, Boolean> cache = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        cache.put(i*1000 + j, true);
    }
}
```

This code finishes in 97 milliseconds.

Not `Arrays.asList` neither `Map.put` is slow. Maybe the hash function of the list is slow

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        Arrays.asList(i, j).hashCode();
    }
}
```

This code finishes in 101 milliseconds.

No. This is fast as well. So maybe hash values collide most of the time. To test this, I put all hash codes inside a set and checked its size.

```
Set<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        hashSet.add(Arrays.asList(i, j).hashCode());
    }
}
System.out.println(hashSet.size());
```

And it gave 31969. 31969 out of 1000000 is about %3,2. I think this is the source of the slowness. 1m item is too much for HashMap. It starts to move away from `O(1)` as more and more collisions occur.

Comment: That's a nice observation, but that would imply that the impact is on the `containsKey` and `get` which is what the collisions would affect. But measuring that altgough I did notice that the performance is fluctuating it ranges between less than 50ms to a max of 400ms. I think that is due to small lists per bucket hence still keeping at ~O(1). Is that what you would expect?

Comment: This new class decreased running time more than 10x, but still 10x slower than c-like array implementation (see the first code in my answer). I assume this is because of the extra operations and conditions HashMap uses since c-like array allows instant access. I tested these two like the tests in my answer and indeed there is a 10x running time factor.

Comment: Another reason why O(N³) algorithm outperforms the O(N²) one is hidden constant factors. Bruteforce algorithm has very small constant factors. But O(N²) algorithm can be made faster with some optimizations.

Comment: `1m item is too much for HashMap` how did you come up with the 1ms?

Comment: I meant 1 million, sorry for the confusion.