# Hashcode from the string concat of the fields vs the autogenerated approach

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, collision, hashcode

If we have a class such as the following:

```
class ConnectedPair {
        private String source;
        private String destination;

        public ConnectedPair(String source, String destination) {
            if(source == null || destination == null) {  
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
            this.source = source;
            this.destination = destination;
        }
}
```

And we want to use it in a `HashMap` or `HashSet` we would need to implement the `equals` and `hashCode`
The autogenerated `hashCode` for this class is:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = source.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + destination.hashCode();
    return result;
}
```

But I was wondering if instead we did the following:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (source + "=>" + destination).hashCode();
}
```

Is this better or worse than the autogenerated approach? Similar approach is being used in other scripting languages as I have seen and I was wondering if the hash generated is better or worse (or there is no difference).

**Note**: Let's ignore the string concat as performance downside assuming this can be cached and hence optimized

Answer (score 2):

0. They are both fine if all you care about is a valid implementation and have no specific requirements about how likely accidental and/or intentional collisions are. This is the majority of the cases: you can stop investigating here.
1. Both of these suffer from the rather bad definition of `String.hashCode()`. For historical reasons `String.hashCode()` has a fixed definition of how it works and that definition is ... bad. It's prone to accidental collisions and makes it easy to  construct intentional collisions.
2. The second one (with string concatenation) makes it *exceedingly* simple to construct two `ConnectedPair` objects with identical hash codes (`new ConnectedPair("a=>b", "c").hashCode() == new ConnectedPair("a","b=>c").hashCode()`). The other option doesn't entirely prevent this, but makes it slightly harder to construct a sample.
3. This might sound silly, but the generated one is idiomatic: Every Java developer that sees this code will quickly understand what you are doing. Your "custom" implementation doesn't seem significantly worse, but will require slightly more brain power to parse. And remember: code is much more frequently read than written.

Comment: Concerning (1) does that mean we should avoid `String.hashCode()` altogether? So for this specific class where the only fields are `String` how could it be replaced?

Comment: @Jim: see #0: none of these issues are major and often will not matter at all. They *could* become problematic, depending on how you use them (for example, if untrusted users can freely add elements and you hold them all into a `HashMap` then they could force tons of collisions and degrade system performance). In other words: your implementations are in the general area of "okay" `Object.hashCode` implementations. Even the best `hashCode` implementations come nowhere near the gold standard of real cryptographic hashes and that's usually fine.

Comment: Is this just a theoretical concern then? I would have thought that except that I actually encountered "degradation"/poor performance due to collision in another case with pair of ints where the data just had a specific "structure" i.e. all pair of points to 1000 Check here if you have the time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67132326/why-is-this-dp-algo-slower-than-the-brute-forcea-algo/67142950?noredirect=1#comment118694944_67142950

Comment: It's one of those issues that's purely theoretical until it isn't. In normal operation it should be fine, but one day you realize that users can interact with your public server, the JDK isn't patched to the latest version and the `HashMap` holding some internal cache collapses toward linear scan mode, effectively running a DOS attack. I'm not saying that it's **likely**, in fact I think item #0 is the most relevant one of my answer, but it's possible.